# django base.html doesnt exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

This is my file tree

[image]

this is my error
[image]
this is views.py

```
def signup(request):
    proj = project.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'Homepage/Projects.html', {'form': form,"project":proj})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('projects/', Homepage.views.signup, name='projects')
]
```

my settings.py

[image]

html

[image]

did i miss something?

in my venv folder

[image]

Comment: I don't see any "base.html" file in your folder tree image. Where is it?

Comment: wait a sec, ill posts it

Comment: please see my update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the base.html of django admin site.

You need to create a base.html file inside your Homepage>templates folder so that you can use that as {% extends 'base.html' %}

Comment: is there global base.html for sign up ?